# How to redirect after logging in?React

Tags: reactjs

So what I am trying to do here is to create a login system in react with this https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/warp/etn-device-checker-test/1.0#/default/post_login api but I am not sure how to redirect it to /home if the email and password are correct. Token might also be needed here

Login.js

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    
   
  
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const getIn = {
      
        "login":email,
        "password":password,
        
    
      };
  
      axios
        .post('https://js-test-api.etnetera.cz/api/v1/login', getIn,
        {
            headers: {
               
                 'content-type': 'application/json', 
           }
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data); 
          return <Redirect to="/home" />
         
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
       
    };
    return (
        <div>
           <form >
         <label>email</label> <input value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} type="text"/>
        <label>password</label>  <input type="text" value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={onSubmit}>login</button>
           </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './Login';
import MobileList from './mobileList';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
 <Router>
 <Switch>
 
<Route>
<Login path='/' exact/>
</Route>
<Route>
 <MobileList path='/home' />
 </Route>
</Switch>
 </Router>
 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/History_API) where you can push an URI,

or just simply do:

`window.location.href = "/home";`

and request for authentication to your server.

Don't forget to redirect your user from MobileList component back to login if they're not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here can be easily fixed with hooks. Instead of returning a jsx component named Redirect you can use the useHistory hook to push the user into the new url.

First import the hook from router.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

Define a variable using the hook before the axios call.

```
let history = useHistory();
```

then change the .then function after the axios request to be this.

```
  .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data); 
      history.push("/home");
    })
```

Comment: it is throwing error at the history.push Unexpected use of 'history'  no-restricted-globals

Comment: Oh Sorry I accidently deleted the code snippet line before the axios call. 

You should write 
  let history = useHistory();
before the axios call. Hope it works now!

Comment: Nope it doesnt redirect, I am starting to think its smth with the token